# How do I set a default host container in traefik with the docker backend?

Tags: reverse-proxy, traefik

I have a reverse proxy setup using traefik.  It's great!

I am trying to figure how to configure it such that when someone goes to `HOSTNAME` or `www.HOSTNAME`, that I can have it default route to some container/subdomain of my choosing.  Assume valid DNS records.

I have a config toml file [here](https://gist.github.com/cdaringe/ffac907f25b0fef4c4d962bb71b600b6).  I then launch a bunch of containers, which the docker backend watches & picks up.  For example,

```
static:
    image: myrepo/static
    volumes:
      - /www/static:/www/static
    depends_on:
      - traefik
    labels:
      - "traefik.backend=static"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:static.$HOSTNAME"
```

Browsing to `static.HOSTNAME` works right now. Yahoo!  But suppose I want a browse to `HOSTNAME` to also serve `static.HOSTNAME`.

Any tips would be great!  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

A CSV of rules can be provided:

```
- "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:<subdomain>.$HOSTNAME,$HOSTNAME"
```

Answer (score 3):

I used a regex rules (catchall in example here):

```
labels:
  - traefik.http.routers.customname.rule=HostRegexp(`{catchall:.*}`)
```

*Traefik 2.0*

Comment: Are we sure that it will be used as a fallback if no other rule matches? I think the intention is that it matches only if "no other configured domain matches explicitly"